# How to prevent PDO from interpreting a question mark as a placeholder?

Tags: php, postgresql, pdo

For detecting the existence of a key in a [hstore](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/hstore.html), I need to run a query like this:

```
SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE hst ? 'foo'
```

However, that gives me a PDOException:

```
PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: no parameters were bound: SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE hst ? 'foo'
```

Is there any way to escape the question mark so PDO won't pick it up as a placeholder? I've tried with up to four backslashes, as well as a double question mark (`??`), but nothing seems to persuade PDO to leave the question mark alone.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Use the function call form. According to the system catalogs, the hstore `?` operator uses the `exist` function:

```
regress=# select oprname, oprcode from pg_operator where oprname = '?';
 oprname | oprcode 
---------+---------
 ?       | exist
(1 row)
```

so you can write:

```
SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE exist(hst,'foo');
```

(Personally I'm not a big fan of hstore's operator-centric design and documentation, I think it discards the useful self-documenting properties of a function based interface without any real benefit and I usually use its function calls rather than its operators. Just because you can define operators doesn't mean you should.)

Comment: i am using this for now, but unfortunately there is not a function replacement for ?& and ?| operators.  I guess i can write my own... sucks.

Comment: Eh? There has to be a function backing any operator. Sure enough, plugging them into the above, `?&` is `exists_all` and `?|` is `exists_any`.

Comment: When substituting the `?` operator for use with JSONB data types, replace `EXIST()` with `JSONB_EXISTS()`.

Answer (score 13):

I had the same problem when searching on JSONB data. The full question is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36173440/how-to-ignore-question-mark-as-placeholder-when-using-pdo-with-postgresql)

```sql
SELECT * FROM post WHERE locations ? :location;
```

The workaround on `PostgreSQL 9.5` is similar:

```sql
SELECT * FROM post WHERE jsonb_exists(locations, :location);
```

I also opened a [ticket](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=71885) at PHP bug tracing system

### Update

As Diabl0 mentioned, the proposed solution work but does not use the index.
Tested with:

```
CREATE INDEX tempidxgin ON post USING GIN (locations);
```

Comment: Please do not post your answer for all the questions of this kind. instead, mark them as a duplicate.

Comment: @YourCommonSense I mentioned that the workaround (solution) is different and worthwhile emphasizing. I have no idea what do you mean by all. It is focused and defined in the appropriate places.

Comment: This solution as it works has one huge downside - querying using jsonb functions don't use indexes which may lead to significant performance downgrade.

Answer (score -3):

I suggest you disable PDO native prepared statement so question marks will be ignored:

```
$pdo->setAttribute(\PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, true);
```

Comment: Whichever way you set this parameter, PDO does some statement parsing, and misinterprets the `?`.

Comment: This answer works for me, though it didn't on a version of PHP I was using before. Tried to change downvote to upvote, won't let me unless you revise ;)

Comment: This solution is in the right direction to a "no surprise" pure SQL player.
However it seems to depend on both PHP version, and the driver used; and it is not clear (from PHP documentation) what exactly we loose be removing emulation (here too the answer seems to be driver-dependent).

Here it works with PHP 7.2 + PostgreSQL 14.

Comment: For PostgreSQL: the PHP code tells that ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES implies an internal emulate that (paradoxily) implies PDO_PLACEHOLDER_NONE (that I understand as "do emulate neither ? nor :param").
So for PostgreSQL, counter-intuitively, *activating* emulation *deactivates* all kind of preprocessing by PDO; thus the ? gets passed to the PQ library (PostgreSQL client library) which does the right thing (use ? as an operator, not a param placeholder).