# Query array of objects (Postgres with JSONB, Laravel 5)

Tags: php, postgresql, laravel, laravel-5, jsonb

I've got this data in a JSONB field:

```
[
    'first_name' => 'Philipp',
    'last_name' => 'Kühn',
    'size' => 170,
    'hobbies' => [
      'daily' => 'beer',
    ],
    'skills' => [
      'drink beer',
      'drink more beer',
    ],
]
```

I'm pretty new to Laravel and Postgres so I wanted to do some basic queries.

Here are some queries that works fine:
(json is the name of the column)

```
$users = User::whereRaw("json ->> 'first_name' = 'Philipp'")->get();

$users = User::whereRaw("json ->> 'size' > '160'")->get();

$users = User::whereRaw("json #>> '{hobbies, daily}' = 'beer'")->get();
```

Now I want to check if `drink beer` is in `skills` and the following code doesn't work:

```
$users = User::whereRaw("json -> 'skills' ? 'drink beer'")->get();
```

Here I got a syntax error:

```
SQLSTATE[42601]: Syntax error: 7 ERROR: syntax error at or near "$1"
LINE 1: select * from "users" where json ->> 'skills' $1 'drink beer...
^ (SQL: select * from "users" where json ->> 'skills' ? 'drink beer')
```

How can I search for `drink beer`?

Comment: Hu ho, it sounds PDO is taking the question mark as being a query parameter… Look at the documentation : positional parameters : http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php No idea how to get around this.

Comment: yes. this seems to be the problem. i've tested a raw query in postico and everything worked. argh...

Comment: what about http://stackoverflow.com/a/16312053/244058 ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As suggested by @tapoueh on twitter, maybe a work around would be to use the operator's underlying function: `jsonb_exists(jsonb, text)`. So your query would be

```
$users = User::whereRaw("jsonb_exists(json -> 'skills', 'drink beer')")->get();
```

Added by @docteur_klein : [A link to a similar problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16311939/how-to-prevent-pdo-from-interpreting-a-question-mark-as-a-placeholder/16312053#16312053).

Comment: missing `)` , check your query once again

Answer (score 3):

With 
[Laravel 5.6+](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/queries) searching in a JSON becomes really easy

https://laravel.com/api/5.6/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.html#method_whereJsonContains

```
User::WhereJsonContains('json->skills', 'drink beer')->get();
```

Comment: Your link is 404. New URL is https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/queries#json-where-clauses

Answer (score 1):

If you need LIKE search, then use that:

```
\DB::table('users')
    ->whereRaw("json::json->>'skills' like '%drive a car%'")
    ->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to search an value item inside array of objects, you can escape strings like this:

```
$query = "column @> '{\"INDEX_OF_ARRAY\":[{\"INDEX_OF_OBJECT\": \"".$searched_value."\"}]}'";
$colection = YourModel::whereRaw($query);
$colection->get();
```