# How to ignore question mark as placeholder when using PDO with PostgreSQL

Tags: php, postgresql, pdo

## Note:

This question can be considered as duplicate of this [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16311939/how-to-prevent-pdo-from-interpreting-a-question-mark-as-a-placeholder).
It does point to the same problem with PDO. But its workaround solution is a bit different as the target differ. I will post there the workaround for JSONB and the link to the PHP ticket.

When I prepare the following query:

```sql
SELECT * FROM post WHERE locations ? :location;
```

The following warning occur:

> Warning: PDO::prepare(): SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: mixed named and positional parameters in /path/file.php on line xx

The question mark is an valid [PostgreSQL operator](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/functions-json.html) but PDO condsider it as a placeholder.

Is there a proper way to configure PDO to ignore question mark as placeholders?

**I will post a workaround bellow. Hoping there is a better way**

**Edit**
I add a [ticket](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=71885) at PHP bug tracing system

Comment: It's been asked few times already, e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16311939/how-to-prevent-pdo-from-interpreting-a-question-mark-as-a-placeholder No good answer tho.

Comment: @AlexBlex, yes and no. I read that question (and several others) but its not the same. Check my workaround. I will open a ticket at PHP PDO to address this

Comment: Actually, both question and answer look duplicate to me - mikl was using a `?` operator (in this case, on hstore rather than json) and Craig Ringer suggested using a function as a workaround (looking up the built-in function that implements the operator, rather than creating a new one).

Comment: BTW Not sure about PHP/PDO but try to remove the space between column name and operator: `WHERE locations? :location;`

Comment: @Abelisto Unfortunately, PDO's parser is too smart, and still spots the `?`, according to my tests.

Comment: This should be solved in the not too distant future by this change to the PHP PDO extentsion: https://wiki.php.net/rfc/pdo_escape_placeholders

Answer (score 6):

This is a workaround to my problem. It solve the problem by using PostgreSQL function to replace the `?` operator.

I don't really like it because it does not make PDO more compliance to PostgreSQL. But I found no real solution.

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION json_key_exists(JSONB,TEXT) RETURNS BOOLEAN LANGUAGE SQL STABLE AS $f$
    SELECT $1 ? $2
$f$;
```

And now I can use the query:

```sql
SELECT * FROM post WHERE json_key_exists(locations, :location);
```

The workaround was suggested by the fabulous RhodiumToad from freenode #postgresql

## Edit

As @Abelisto suggested, there is no need to create the function above as `jsonb_exists(jsonb, text)` is avialabe

Comment: You can to explore the `?` operator definition (`\do+ "?"` in psql) and find out that it uses function `jsonb_exists(jsonb, text)` as its background. So you does not need to define your function but reuse already existed one.

Comment: I'd like to suggest using custom immutable function with `?` inside, as for **jsonb_exists() is not indexable, whereas `?` is**. See https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/90002/postgresql-operator-uses-index-but-underlying-function-does-not

Comment: @НЛО You are wrong BTW. `create index i on t(jsonb_exists(x,'a'::text));` and index used fine too.

Answer (score 6):

Since PHP 7.4, [supports for escaping question mark have landed](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/pdo_escape_placeholders).

> (...) question marks can be escaped by doubling them (...). That means that the “??” string would be translated to “?” when sending the query to the database, whereas “?” is still going to be interpreted as a positional parameter placeholder.

In your example, you can use:

```php
$sql = "SELECT * FROM post WHERE locations ?? :location;";
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok, the simplest way is to [create the new operator](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createoperator.html) with the same options, like:

```
-- Operator: ~!@#%^&(jsonb, text)

-- DROP OPERATOR ~!@#%^&(jsonb, text);

CREATE OPERATOR 
  ~!@#%^& -- Change it to any other non-conflicted symbols combination
(
  PROCEDURE = jsonb_exists,
  LEFTARG = jsonb,
  RIGHTARG = text,
  RESTRICT = contsel,
  JOIN = contjoinsel);
COMMENT ON OPERATOR ~!@#%^&(jsonb, text) IS 'key exists';
```

(Original script was generated by pgAdmin)

And use it in usual way like

```
SELECT * FROM post WHERE locations ~!@#%^& :location;
```

Comment: Great workaround. I guess the decision of which one to use will be related to the type and the quantity of the queries.

Answer (score 1):

You can use

- `jsonb_exists` instead of `?`
- `jsonb_exists_any` instead of `?|`
- `jsonb_exists_all` instead of `?&`

But there is no documentions on [postgresql site](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html#FUNCTIONS-JSONB-OP-TABLE).

Comment: Undefined function: 7 ERROR: function jsonb_exists_any(json, text[]) does not exist, postgres 10

Answer (score 0):

For searching keys and according to Yoann answer, I have tested that the expression ( jsonbData ? 'keySearched' ) is equivalent to jsonb_exists(jsonbData , 'keySearched')

Answer (score 0):

Use `CREATE OPERATOR ~@& (LEFTARG = jsonb, RIGHTARG = text[], PROCEDURE = jsonb_exists_any)` and use ~@& instead ?| everything will works fine

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
jsonb_exists(some_jsonb_array,'search_value');
```