# cakephp condition using '?' in the string

Tags: postgresql, cakephp, cakephp-2.0, cakephp-3.0, jsonb

Is there any way to make a condition using '?', ex.: Model.field ? 'value'.
I trying to make a query in a jsonb type column in postgresql, but it seems that PDO handles the character as a placeholder.

Comment: **http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16311939/how-to-prevent-pdo-from-interpreting-a-question-mark-as-a-placeholder**

Comment: thx man, the explanation works very well!