# Execute query with "?|" operator

Tags: php, postgresql, laravel, pdo, laravel-5.3

I have table `my_table` with [jsonb](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-json.html) column `sentiments`. I need to remove all keys '10216' and '10191' from this column.

I try to do next in Laravel:

```
DB::table('my_table')
    ->whereRaw("sentiments ?| ARRAY['10216', '10191']")
    ->update([
        'sentiments' => DB::raw("sentiments - '10216' - '10191'")
    ]);
```

But I have next error:

```
[Illuminate\Database\QueryException]                                                                                 
  SQLSTATE[42601]: Syntax error: 7 ОШИБКА:  ошибка синтаксиса (примерное положение: "$1")                              
  LINE 1: ...= sentiments - '10216' - '10191' where sentiments $1| ARRAY[...                                           
                                                               ^ (SQL: update "my_table" 
    set "sentiments" = sentiments - '10216' - '10191' 
    where sentiments ?| ARRAY['10216', '10191'])
```

Because as I see "?" looks like parameter. How to escape this symbol?

**UPDATE**

Also I tried to write two questions: `sentiments ??| ARRAY`:

```
[Illuminate\Database\QueryException]                                                                                 
  SQLSTATE[42883]: Undefined function: 7 ОШИБКА:  оператор не существует: jsonb ??| text[]                             
  LINE 1: ...= sentiments - '10216' - '10191' where sentiments ??| ARRAY[...                                           
                                                               ^                                                       
  HINT:  Оператор с данными именем и типами аргументов не найден. Возможно, вам следует добавить явные приведения тип  
  ов. (SQL: update "my_table" set "sentiments" = sentiments - '10216' - '10191' where sentiments ??|  
   ARRAY['10216', '10191'])
```

Comment: did you try ?? (two question marks)

Comment: @degr: thanks for idea, but it not helps. I has updated answer.

Comment: check this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16311939/how-to-prevent-pdo-from-interpreting-a-question-mark-as-a-placeholder

Comment: @degr: Thanks! It works: `jsonb_exists_any(sentiments, array['10216', '10191'])`. Please, post answer, I will accept.

Comment: it's not my answer, you did it by self

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Thanks to @degr! it works with undocumented function `jsonb_exists_any()`:

```
DB::table('my_table')
    ->whereRaw("jsonb_exists_any(sentiments, ARRAY['10216', '10191'])")
    ->update([
        'sentiments' => DB::raw("sentiments - '10216' - '10191'")
    ]);
```

**UPDATE**

With this approach indexes on jsonb field are not used unlike using operator `?|`.

Comment: Undefined function: 7 ERROR:  function jsonb_exists_any(json, text[]) does not exist, postgres 10

Comment: @LevonBabayan try to onvert first parameter to `jsonb`

Answer (score 2):

Dear friend you can use

> CREATE OPERATOR ~@& (LEFTARG = jsonb, RIGHTARG = text[], PROCEDURE = jsonb_exists_any)

and write your query with like this

```
DB::table('my_table')
->whereRaw("sentiments ~@& ARRAY['10216', '10191']")
->update([
    'sentiments' => DB::raw("sentiments - '10216' - '10191'")
]);
```