# 'Invalid schema name' error thrown by Doctrine, but the raw SQL seems to work

Tags: doctrine-orm, dql, postgresql-9.5, doctrine-query

I'm using some custom DQL functions to filter rows by some JSONB fields in PostgreSQL. Here's my query function:

```
private function findTopLevelResources(): array {
    return $this->createQueryBuilder('r')
        ->where("JSON_EXISTS(r.contents, '-1') = FALSE")
        ->getQuery()
        ->getResult();
}
```

Running this code results in `DriverException` from `AbstractPostgreSQLDriver`:

```
An exception occurred while executing 'SELECT r0_.id AS id_0, r0_.marking AS marking_1, r0_.contents AS contents_2, r0_.kind_id AS kind_id_3 FROM resource r0_ WHERE r0_.contents?'-1' = false':

SQLSTATE[3F000]: Invalid schema name: 7 ERROR: schema "r0_" does not exist
LINE 1: ... r0_.kind_id AS kind_id_3 FROM resource r0_ WHERE r0_.conten...
                                                             ^
```

I tried to execute the raw SQL query manually from PHPStorm and it worked, no errors.

**How do I get this to work in Doctrine?**

**Why doesn't this query work with Doctrine, but does when I test it manually?**

---

Here's `JSON_EXISTS`: (based on [syslogic/doctrine-json-functions](https://packagist.org/packages/syslogic/doctrine-json-functions))

```
class JsonExists extends FunctionNode
{
    const FUNCTION_NAME = 'JSON_EXISTS';
    const OPERATOR = '?';

    public $jsonData;
    public $jsonPath;

    public function getSql(SqlWalker $sqlWalker)
    {
        $jsonData = $sqlWalker->walkStringPrimary($this->jsonData);
        $jsonPath = $this->jsonPath->value;
        return $jsonData . self::OPERATOR . "'$jsonPath'";
    }

    public function parse(Parser $parser)
    {
        $parser->match(Lexer::T_IDENTIFIER);
        $parser->match(Lexer::T_OPEN_PARENTHESIS);

        $this->jsonData = $parser->StringPrimary();

        $parser->match(Lexer::T_COMMA);

        $this->jsonPath = $parser->StringPrimary();

        $parser->match(Lexer::T_CLOSE_PARENTHESIS);
    }
}
```

Registered via Symfony's YAML config like this:

```
doctrine:
  orm:
    dql:
      numeric_functions:
        json_exists: Syslogic\DoctrineJsonFunctions\Query\AST\Functions\Postgresql\JsonExists
```

Versions of stuff:

- PHP                                        7.1.1
- doctrine/dbal                              v2.6.1
- doctrine/orm                               dev-master e3ecec3 (== 2.6.x-dev)
- symfony/symfony                            v3.3.4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The error message is a false clue.**

Actual problem is caused by PDO (this is why it works from PHPStorm). When it sees a query like this:

```
SELECT * FROM foo WHERE contents?'bar'
```

It treats it like a parametrized query and the question mark `?` as a parameter. For some reason it sometimes results in nonsensical error messages. This specific case could be solved by adding a space after the question mark, but it won't work for operators `?|` and `?&` which can't have a space in the middle.

The solution is to use functions corresponding to operators ([this question saved the day](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16312053/1937994)). One can find out how they are called using queries like this one:

```
SELECT oprname, oprcode FROM pg_operator WHERE oprname IN ('?', '?|', '?&')
```

Here's the part of result related to JSON:

- `?` → `jsonb_exists`
- `?|` → `jsonb_exists_any`
- `?&` → `jsonb_exists_all`

So instead of previous query which causes problems via PDO, one can use this equivalent one:

```
SELECT * FROM foo WHERE jsonb_exists(contents, 'bar')
```