# PDO How to use `?` in query without binding data for that symbol

Tags: php, postgresql, symfony, pdo, doctrine

in Symfony project I executed native query for postgres. And I have one query with condition for search by column with type jsonb . But when I try to represend in for PDO I faced with error

Native query which did not throw error and works correct

```
         WHERE products_alias.extras -> 'SIZE' ?| array['91', '38']
```

query for PDO

```
         WHERE (products_alias.extras -> :size_extra_key ?| array[:values_size_extra_key_0,:values_size_extra_key_1])
```

params for PDO

```
params = {array} [5]
 :values_size_extra_key_0 = "140"
 :values_size_extra_key_1 = "86"
 :size_extra_key = "SIZE"
```

PDO execute query, point where should be statement with result

```
    /** @var ResultCacheStatement $statement */
    $statement = $connection->executeCacheQuery(
        $query,
        $params,
        $types,
        $queryCacheProfile
    );
```

I faced with error

```
SQLSTATE[42601]: Syntax error: 7 ERROR:  syntax error at or near "$2"
LINE 39:              WHERE (products_alias.extras -> $1 $2| array[$3...
```

I was try replace symbol question to variable but still faced with error

```
                            LEFT JOIN user_ip_product uip on uip.products_id = products_alias.id               
             WHERE (products_alias.extras -> ? ?| array[?,?])
                    GROUP BY products_alias.id
            ) AS main_products_alias
            GROUP BY main_products_alias.group_identity ORDER BY "createdAt" DESC

                    LIMIT ?
                    OFFSET ?;
            ' with params ["SIZE", "?", "140", "86", 10, 0]:

SQLSTATE[42601]: Syntax error: 7 ERROR:  syntax error at or near "$2"
LINE 39:              WHERE (products_alias.extras -> $1 $2| array[$3...
```

How to use `?` in query without binding data for that symbol ?

**UPDATE**

```
select oprname, oprcode from pg_operator where oprname = '?'


?   jsonb_exists
?   exist
```

But how to apply `jsonb_exists` for my query ?

Comment: I think https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16311939/how-to-prevent-pdo-from-interpreting-a-question-mark-as-a-placeholder may help, if it does then this can be closed as a duplicate.

Comment: hmm , but how t use `jsonb_exists` and it whould be the same logic ? I udatte question